# Is there a good way to cancel a blocking read?

Tags: go

I've got a command I have to run via the OS, let's call it 'login', that is interactive and therefore requires me to read from the stdin and pass it to the command's stdin pipe in order for it to work correctly. The only problem is the goroutine blocks on a read from stdin and I haven't been able to find a way to cancel a Reader in Go in order to get it to not hang on the blocking call. For example, from the perspective of the user, after the command looks as if it completed, you still have the opportunity to write to stdin once more (then the goroutine will move past the blocking read and exit)

Ideally I would like to avoid having to parse output from the command's StdoutPipe as that makes my code frail and prone to error if the strings of the `login` command were to change.

```golang
loginCmd := exec.Command("login")
stdin , err := loginCmd.StdinPipe()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

out, err := loginCmd.StdoutPipe()

if err != nil {
    return err
}

if err := loginCmd.Start(); err != nil {
    return err
}

ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.TODO())
var done sync.WaitGroup
done.Add(1)
ready := make(chan bool, 1)
defer cancel()
go func(ctx context.Context) {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    for {
        select {
        case <- ctx.Done():
            done.Done()
            return
        default:
            //blocks on this line, if a close can unblock the read, then it should exit normally via the ctx.Done() case
            line, err :=reader.ReadString('\n')
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error: ", err.Error())
            }
            stdin.Write([]byte(line))
        }
    }
}(ctx)

var bytesRead = 4096
output := make([]byte, bytesRead)
reader := bufio.NewReader(out)
for err == nil {
    bytesRead, err = reader.Read(output)
    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", output[:bytesRead])
}

if err := loginCmd.Wait(); err != nil {
    return err
}
cancel()
done.Wait()
```

Comment: Parsing the output for some sequence that indicates it's the user's turn to provide input seems like the more "correct" approach - operating based on timeout is also fragile, in that it a) means your program can't operate faster than timeout; and b) may behave incorrectly when the program it's forking operates slower than expected.

Comment: Are you doing anything else after `loginCmd` exits? If not, you can just exit from your Go program instead of canceling the context and waiting for your goroutine to finish.

Comment: @AndySchweig unfortunately yes, this method is one small part of a larger function

Comment: You can't cancel a Read from Stdin, just leave the goroutine running and make sure it can't effect the program if it completes later on.

Comment: @JimB what about if I opened up a `bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdin)` and wrote a newline character, would that technically unblock the read to stdin?

Comment: @sreya: no, because stdin is a tty. The only real way around this is to not use a Read directly, and use the syscall package to select (or equiv) on the fd and either poll or pair it with a pipe which you can use to signal an exit (i.e. the "self-pipe trick"). There generally no reason to go through the hassle, when you can just leave the goroutine and not worry about it.

Comment: @JimB: Why don't you turn your comment into an answer?